# getting error on vite build in vue3 vite project

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I have prepared my vue3 project with vite. In localhost, if I run `npm run dev` it is working properly and running the website file. If I run `npm run build` then it is not working. I have attached the error message as an image. Please check

TIA

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some npm packages, I have used in my project have some features were added from the latest EcmaScript. Like async generator functions, for-await, etc. Vite used the **esbuild** library to bundle javascript. If we don’t set the target, the transform by **esbuild** doesn’t work properly. To solve this issue need to set a target in the build command (package.json)

```
vite build --target=es2020
```